# How to use variable while using filter and contains in cypress

Tags: cypress

i want to use variable instead of string while using filter and contains using cypress.

below is my cypress

```js
const var = "somestring";

cy.get('div[attr="value"])
    .filter(':contains("somestring"))'
    .should('have.length', 1);
```

the above works. but i wanted to user variable instead of passing string "somestring" directly to filter.

something like below,

```js
const var = "somestring";
cy.get('div[attr="value"])
    .filter(':contains(var))'
    .should('have.length', 1);
```

but this does not work as i have passed var inside quotes and is considered string.

how can i pass the var for contains. could you someone help me with this. I am new to cypress and programming. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this. Something like:

```
const var = "somestring";
cy.get('div[attr="value"]')
    .filter(`:contains(“${var}”)`)
    .should('have.length', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compose the selector string as follows:

```js
const textOfElement = "somestring";

const filterSelector = `:contains("${textOfElement}")`          // templated string   
// or
// const filterSelector = ':contains("' + textOfElement + '")'  // concatenated string

cy.get('div[attr="value"])
  .filter(filterSelector)
  .should('have.length', 1);
```